# Minipage inside tabular is out of table

Tags: tables, minipage, minted

I intended to add code inside a `tabular` environment using the `minted` package. I found out that using a `minipage` inside a `tabular` environment allows me to use the `minted` environment inside a table cell.

But the problem I'm facing now is, that the `minted` output always seems to be located outside of the table, no matter what options I choose. For better visualization of the problem, I added vertical lines between columns.

Example code:

```
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|}
        HTTP-Verb & \texttt{POST} \\
        Path & \texttt{/users} \\
        Request-Body & 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{minted}{js}
                {
                    "username": "string",
                    "mail": "string"
                }
            \end{minted}
        \end{minipage} \\
        Response-Body & - \\
        Description & \makecell{Creates a new user.}
    \end{tabular}
```

Output:

[image]

I also noticed that the next rows content of the same column the `minipage` is at, is affected by the `minipage`s width.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Remember that spaces are preserved inside a `minted` environment, so if you have 15 spaces at the start of a line ...

Comment: you do not need a minipage, it would be simpler just to use an appropriate column type for the second column `p{.3\textwidth}` not `l`

Answer (score 1):

Torbjørn T.'s comment lead to the solution of my problem. Quote:

> Remember that spaces are preserved inside a minted environment, so if you have 15 spaces at the start of a line ...

Right at the beginning of the debugging process I suspected this to be the issue. So I added the showspaces option of the minted package without getting any changes in the output. I should have just removed the spaces, since this resolved the problem. Silly me...

Comment: The comment is not mine but Torbjorn's...

Comment: Why do you assume that CarLaTeX is a "he"? (Hint: Contemplate the potential meaning of the substring "Carla" contained in the person's userid.) Bigger question: Why do you make *any* assumption about the gender of a person who (almost surely) isn't known to you?

Comment: Thank you for the corrections. I didn't mean to be disrespectful, neither by making gender assumptions nor by stating the wrong user. I promise to pay more attention in future posts :)

Comment: Thank you @Mico! Don't worry phil155, it's an error often done, I did it, too! However, my name is Carla and I'm a woman :):):)